# How to stop traversing current root and iterate to the next one

Tags: python, python-3.x, tree-traversal, os.walk

I'm writing a simple function that walks through a directory tree looking for folders of a certain name. What I'm after is a match's parent path. E.g., for "C:/a/b/c/MATCH" I want "C:/a/b/c". I don't need duplicate parents or paths to subfolder matches, so if there's a "C:/a/b/c/d/e/f/MATCH", I don't need it. So, during my walk, once I have a parent, I want to iterate to the next current root.

Below is what I have so far, including a comment where I'm stuck.

```
def FindProjectSubfolders(masterPath, projectSubfolders):
    for currRoot, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(masterPath):
        # check if have a project subfolder
        foundMatch = False
        for dirname in dirnames:
            for projectSubfolder in projectSubfolders:
                if (dirname == projectSubfolder):
                    foundMatch = True;
                    break
        if (foundMatch == True):
            # what goes here to stop traversing "currRoot"
            # and iterate to the next one?
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Trim `dirnames` to an empty list to prevent further traversing of directories below the current one:

```
def FindProjectSubfolders(masterPath, projectSubfolders):
    for currRoot, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(masterPath):
        # check if have a project subfolder
        foundMatch = False
        for dirname in dirnames:
            for projectSubfolder in projectSubfolders:
                if (dirname == projectSubfolder):
                    foundMatch = True;
                    break
        if (foundMatch == True):
            # what goes here to stop traversing "currRoot"
            # and iterate to the next one?
            dirnames[:] = []  # replace all indices in `dirnames` with the empty list
```

Note that the above code alters the list `dirnames` refers to with a slice assignment, it does *not* rebind `dirnames` to a new list.