# Create list using regex inputs

Tags: python, regex, list, os.walk

I'm searching a very convoluted directory tree using os.walk in python 2.7.7 and want to limit the searching by using a trim in place for the resultant directories

```
import os,re
dirExclude = set(['amip4K','amip4xCO2','aqua4K','aqua4xCO2'])
for (path,dirs,files) in os.walk(inpath,topdown=True):
     dirs[:] = [d for d in dirs if d not in dirExclude]
     # Do something
```

I want to append to this dirExclude list/set anything that matches the regular expression r'decadal[0-9]{4}', however am having a hard time determining how best to use a regular expression in my list/set definition?

Any suggestions here? Or indeed a more efficient way to use the os.walk function?

After a number of suggestions the above can be improved to:

```
import os,re
dirExclude = set(['amip4K','amip4xCO2','aqua4K','aqua4xCO2'])
decExclude = re.compile(r'decadal[0-9]{4}')
for (path,dirs,files) in os.walk(inpath,topdown=True):
     dirs[:] = [d for d in dirs if d not in dirExclude and not re.search(decExclude,d)]
     # Do something
```

After investigating the `dir[:] =` versus `dir =` assignment, the `[:]` is needed to ensure that os.walk uses the pruned directory listing, rather than the full (pre-pruned) directory listing

Comment: Does [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17785647/how-to-stop-traversing-current-root-and-iterate-to-the-next-one/17785700#17785700) help?

Comment: I would add to the if part of the list comprehension.  Also, why use dirs[:]?  You are making a copy of the list and then the original is garbage collected.

Comment: Nope, that's a more simplified case - so using that example I want to generate the input projectSubfolders using regex as I have many permutations

Comment: @joelgoldstick: Actually, no. See my answer. In order to "prune" directories, you have to modify the list that `os.walk` references.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of adding to `dirExclude`, why not just check whether there's a match for `r'decadal[0-9]{4}'` in a dirname `d`?

I'm thinking of something like this:

```
import re
dirExclude = set(['amip4K','amip4xCO2','aqua4K','aqua4xCO2'])
exre = re.compile(r'decadal[0-9]{4}')
for (path,dirs,files) in os.walk(inpath,topdown=True):
     dirs = [d for d in dirs if d not in dirExclude and not exre.search(d)]
     # Do something
```

Explanation:

`exre.search(d)` will return `None` if there is no match for your regex inside `d`. `not None` will then evaluate to `True`. Otherwise, `exre.search(d)` will return a `MatchObject` and `not exre.search(d)` will evaluate to `False`.

Compiling the regular expression is optional. Without compiling, you would issue

```
exre = r'decadal[0-9]{4}'
```

and

```
dirs = [d for d in dirs if d not in dirExclude and not re.search(exre, d)]
```

Compiling can be useful when you need to apply a regex a lot of times in order to do the compiling part only once. However, most of the time you won't notice a difference, as even if you don't compile the regex manually Python will cache the last used regexes. To be precise, the last one hundred regexes, though the only reference I got for this is the Regular Expression Cookbook by Jan Goyvaerts and Steven Levithan.

Comment: What is the difference between using re.search and re.compile - is one going to be faster?

Comment: @KarolS your edit to my answer was invalid, please be more careful next time.

Answer (score 1):

Augmenting the previous suggestions, you can use `ifilterfalse` (or `filterfalse` in Python 3.x) to efficiently filter on a regular expression:

```
from itertools import ifilterfalse
import re
import os

exclude = {'foo', 'bar', 'baz'}
expr = re.compile(r'decadal\d{4}')
for (path, dirs, files) in os.walk(inpath):
    dirs[:] = set(ifilterfalse(expr.match, dirs)) - exclude
```

Some further notes:

- Simply doing `dir = [alist]` is insufficient because this only modifies what the *local* label `dir` is referring to (i.e. it is no longer referring to the the `dirs` list that `os.walk` uses). You *must* modify the actual list that `dirs` list that `os.walk` references. You can do this (as above) by doing the slice assignment operator. This more or less equivalent to the expression: `dirs.__setitem__(slice(None, None), [alist])`

Comment: it would seem that my use of dir = (rather than dir[:] =) is actually truncating the dirs variable that os.walk is using - is the behaviour different in python 2.7.x vs 3.x?

Comment: I would check to see if certain directories actually _are_ being pruned, as that is not the behavior of variable assignment in Python.

Comment: You're absolutely right, in python 2.7.7 excluding the [:] means the directories are not pruned at all.. I've updated the code snippet above.. Thanks for making this point again!

Answer (score 0):

If you simply want to avoid all directories that match the re, you could do:

```
d_re = re.compile(r'decadal[0-9]{4}')
dirs = [d for d in dirs if d_re.match(d) is None]
```

You could retrieve all the ignored files at the end by:

```
 dirExclude = dirExclude.union(d for d in dirs if d not in dirExclude)
```

or

```
[dirExclude.add(d) for d in dirs if d not in dirExclude]
```